# Type1 font not found using pdftex

Tags: pdftex, type1

I am encountering problems when installing a `Type1` font, particulary the Rotis family. I fallowed the installation guide provided by Walter Schmidt on [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/metrics/w-a-schmidt/)

Here is my error:

```
...  )) (./schrift.aux) (/Users/jonen/Library/texmf/tex/latex/pro/ot1pro.fd
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./schrift.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+57/600 --dpi 657 pror8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for pror8r.
mktexpk: perhaps pror8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file pror8r): Font pror8r at 657 not found
```

Although is definitely there:

```
kpsewhich pror8r.tfm
/Users/jonen/Library/texmf/fonts/tfm/adobe/rotis/pror8r.tfm


grep pror8r `kpsewhich pdftex.map`
pror8r RotisSerif "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <8r.enc <pror8a.pfb
```

I know this can be caused by mixing up map files, but I have already reinstalled `MacTeX` with no luck.

After placing the files in their appropriate folder I run:

```
texhash
updmap --enable Map pro.map
```

I also tried to run both commands as sudo and updmap-sys but again with no luck.

Comment: It is generally best to avoid `updmap` and stick to `updmap-sys`. If you must install the fonts in your user directory (rather than `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`) you do not need to update the filename database. What does `kpsewhich pdftex.map` give? My guess is a different result from `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` which is used during compilation. If so and if that map file is under `/Users/jonen/.texlive2013` then delete `/Users/jonen/.texlive2013` and rerun `updmap-sys --enable...`. Also try compiling from the command line rather than your editor.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, indeed `kpsewhich pdftex.map` gives: `/Users/jonen/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` and using `\pdfmapfile{/Users/jonen/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}`solves the problem, but is not a good solution right? So it is sufficient to just delete `/Users/jonen/.texmf-var` ?

Comment: Rename it in case it shouldn't be deleted. That way you can put it back if removing it breaks things horribly. I'm guessing this is equivalent to `~/.texlive2013` but I would not delete a directory based on a guess. MacTeX obviously sets things up slightly differently and I can't remember the details which may have changed in any case. Just do something like `mv ~/.texmf-var ~/.texmf-var.2014-06-08` so you don't lose anything. [Note that `~` just denotes your home directory i.e. `/Users/jonen`. Shell shorthand.]

Comment: Gladly I have made a backup of the folder, because after deleting it and running updmap-sys it didn't work. There is no folder named `~/.texlive2013` but `~/.texmf-config` and `~/.texmf-var`

Comment: Do you mean that `updmap-sys` didn't work? That removing the directory did not improve things? Or that removing the directory broke things horribly?

Comment: I'm really not sure what those directories are or what MacTeX uses them for. I tried reading [What Is Installed](https://www.tug.org/mactex/What_Is_Installed.pdf) but it didn't cast any light on things. You could try `updmap-sys --disable pro.map` followed by `updmap-sys --enable Map=pro.map`. Look through the output for errors and to see which files it uses.